# if (tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) FAIL

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a viewController which contains a tableView; I have a UIView in the header of the table and have dragged a searchDisplayController into the view, along with a segmented control. (I didnt want to use the scope for some reasons, incase u were wondering). Now my problem is that  this check 
    if (tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) 
in cellForRow fails even when the user is typing in the searchBar. I have no idea why??!! As far as I know all the delegates etc are hooked up automatically when u drag the controller into a view. The check is only true once the user presses the search button on the keyboard and then scrolls the table a little, and I know this is not how its supposed to work!?

Can anyone shed some light on what might be going on here? Its driving me crazy!

Many thanks

Jules

Comment: Delegates are not normally automatically hooked up.  You must do this yourself.

Comment: You will most likely have to also write your own delegate methods!

Comment: I have implimented the delegate methods and i am getting the callback. This is how I know its not working properly as the if statement in the title behaves strangely, as described above.

Comment: If the search bar is inserted into a view controller's view, the appropriate connections to the search display controller will automatically be configured. From Apples docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i couldnt figure this out so i did it another way. Using a BOOL isSearchTable and setting this in willShowSearchResultsTableView, and willHideSearchResultsTableView.

Comment: You should be using `active` property from `searchDisplayController` instead of introducing a new property and having to worry about its state management.

Answer (score 9):

You could also use `self.searchDisplayController.active`, for example:

```
if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
    return [searchResultArray count];
} else {
    return [regularDataArray count];
}
```

Hope this helps! Although, if you're trying to do this the right way, you should have to a separate data source, one for search and one for the default version.